# How can I get $x$ value from the formula, knowing $y$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the value of $x$ in the following formula.

$$\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x} = y$$

How would the formula look isolating $x$?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this linear algebra? The formula you are attempting to invert is definitely not linear.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: Is this related to interest rate ? If it is, I have posted a few things on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that $x \ll 1$, you can develop using the binomial expansion to get, as @InterstellarProbe wrote
$$y = \sum_{k=1}^n\dbinom{n}{k}(-1)^{k+1}x^{k-1}$$
Now, using series reversion, you could get
$$x=t+\frac{(n-2)}{3}  t^2+\frac{(n-2) (5 n-7)}{36}  t^3+\frac{(n-2)(17 n^2-44 n+29)}{270}   t^4+\cdots$$ where
$$t=-\frac{2 (y-n)}{(n-1) n}$$

Let us try for $n=7$ and $y=4$; this would give the *approximate*
$$x=\frac{12478}{64827}\approx 0.1925$$ while the exact solution, obtained by Newton method, is $\approx 0.1954$.

For sure, under this assumption and using more terms, we should have better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to turn this into a polynomial equation. By the Binomial Theorem:

$$(1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\dbinom{n}{k}(-1)^kx^k$$

Simplifying:
$$\dfrac{1-(1-x)^n}{x} = \sum_{k=1}^n\dbinom{n}{k}(-1)^{k+1}x^{k-1}$$

Thus:
$$y = \sum_{k=1}^n\dbinom{n}{k}(-1)^{k+1}x^{k-1}$$

For $n>5$, this is a polynomial of degree $5$ or higher. Such a polynomial is not guaranteed to be solvable. For $n>2$, you are going to have radicals in the solution for $x$. And for $n=4$ or $n=5$, the cubic and quartic equations have solutions that are very messy (easier to solve algorithmically than with a general formula).

That said, there is no general formula for the inverse function. You can use numerical analysis to find roots of the polynomial that arises, but there is no closed form.